# invalid literal for int() python3.6

Tags: python, int

I am trying to convert as below in python 3.6

```
my_str= 0000063C
int_addr = int(my_str, 16)
```

But I see this error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''

Any idea what I am messing up?

Comment: Use `my_str="0000063C"`

Comment: The code you've posted produces a SyntaxError on the invalid `0000063C` token, not a ValueError on the `int` call.

Comment: I need the flexibility to assign my_str "any" string. When I do print(type(my_str)), I get back a string. But I still see the error :(

Answer (score 2):

Please, try:

```
my_str= "0000063C"
int_addr = int(my_str, 16)
print(int_addr)
```

The issue you are having happens when you have a string that cannot be converted into an int value. For instance, if you run this:

```
my_str= "sdfsdf"
int_addr = int(my_str, 16)
print(int_addr)
```

You get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>    int_addr = int(my_str, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'sdfsdf'
```

It is important that you handle this type of scenarios, since you mentioned in one comment in your question that the variable **my_str** needs to hold any string value. In order to overcome this, you may wrap the conversion in a try and catch, like this:

```
try:
    my_str= "sdfsdf"
    int_addr = int(my_str, 16)
    print(int_addr)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

You can decide how to your code handles the ValueError exception. I just added the keyword **pass**, but add the handling for your specific situation. Hope this helps!